# Javascript: Getting file from local server-side

Tags: javascript, liferay

I have a file on my web server (file.json) and I need to get it in my javascript function. If somebody could advise me on how I need to go about solving my issue, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Have you tried something? Can you share your code?

Comment: And how is this related to Java ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should make it available in server to be accessed as a resource instead of trying to pick it from the FileSystem. Once it can be accessed as a URL, you can use javascript to read it by making a async call. (You can use any JS frameworks to do it and convert to JSON and use)

Comment: Hi teja, i'am creating my json file in the server side and also in the server folder but i can't access to it in remote

Comment: Which server are you using and what technology stack? It should basically be in a public folder.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery's getJSON method. Read [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/)

Comment: Thanks Valentin for your reply, with this method i can just get data from my json file but i need to get the URL file in my server side. For exemple in my xhtml file i have to complete an attribute "source" : represent the path of my file and my file is in my /Users/XX/Destination/test.json .

Comment: Send the source path through ajax call: $.getJSON('path/to/serverside/code', { source: 'local/file/path' }, successHandler); , and on server side use the path to read & return data from file.